# What are good open source / free CRM packages for a freelance software developer?

Tags: crm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open source CRMs](https://superuser.com/questions/14057/open-source-crms)

I have been a freelance software developer for three years now, and I have always managed to maintain all my client contact info through Google mail and contacts, and my cell phone contacts. However, I now want to start actively marketing my services, so I want an application that will, besides providing contact information, also track communications and responses, help me manage direct marketing campaigns and help me better focus those campaigns and other outgoing communiques.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question has been removed.  Dolibarr looks like a good solution, FWiW.  Installs easily and quick setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SugarCRM seems to be popular, is open source, and offers free and paid support options.

[SugarCRM](http://www.sugarforge.org/content/downloads/)